# Jquery resize() api confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following jquery code displaying two alert() boxes. why?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
alert("called-1"); 
});

$(window).bind("resize.test",function(){
  alert("called-2");
});
```

My question is why Jquery calling custom events(i.e event name starts with "resize") after resize() triggers?

jQuery version : 1.12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code binds two event listeners for `resize`. The first one uses the [`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function and the second uses [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), what is both basically the same. A third option would be to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

The only difference is that you gave the second listener a [`namespace`](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) called `test`, separated by a dot (`.`) between `event name` and `namespace`. But this is still a `resize` event listener, and not a custom event!

Namespaces helps you to seperate or group event listeners. For example, you can remove specific listeners:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    console.log("- resize");
});

$(window).on("resize.test", function() {
    console.log("- resize.test");
});

// trigger resize
console.log("first trigger:");
$(window).trigger("resize");

// remove all listeners with '.test' namespace
$(window).off(".test"); // or more specific: $(window).off("resize.test");

// trigger resize again
console.log("second trigger:");
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Official `event.namespace` doc.](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

Answer (score -1):

When the `resize` event is triggered, it will start processing all the actions you have bound to it.

You can bind as many functions as you want to an event.

The jQuery events declaration (`resize.whatevername`) allows you to provide a namespace in order to unbind it later :

```
$(window).unbind('resize.test')
```

But it is still bound to the `resize` event

Comment: This is **NOT** a custom event!